# Is bad choice making pivot table with values?

Tags: php, database, postgresql, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I have a question within designing new DB tables. Is it possible store data just like IDs?

Let's say I have a table where would be:

```
ID   type
1    client_id
2    item_id
3    price
4    date
```

What could go wrong making table like this:

```
ID   transaction   foreign_id   data
1    222           1            14
2    222           2            25
3    222           3            $255
4    222           4            5/17/2020
5    528           1            14
6    528           2            187
7    528           3            $14
8    528           4            5/16/2020
```

etc..

I'm gonna make a much bigger DB where could be more than 20 columns. I'm thinking if this could be a (better) solution. Is there something that could go possibly wrong with this structure?

PS: Postgre DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing the entity-attribute-value model.

I would not actually recommend this, as it comes with many pitfalls, such as:

- integrity of attribute names cannot be enforced (what if someone creates a new attribute called `id_client`, while `client_id` exists already?)
- all values are stored in a single column so you cannot use proper sql datatypes for each attriute (what if someone sets date `2020-00-00`?)
- not possible to enforce the notion of mandatory attribute, or any other type of constraint

On the other hand, all above points are properly managed by creating a table with the relevant number of columns, with proper datatypes and `not null` constraints. 20 columns is not that many - and alternative solutions are possible while use relational tables, such as inheritance.